# XSLT - Round up to two decimal places

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

There is a requirement to round the value up(always) to two decimal places. meaning, the number 8.3333333 should become 8.34. Round and format-number functions do not seem to achieve this. Does anyone have an idea on how to get the desired output using xslt transformation please?

Comment: What would happen with `8.3` or `8.30`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To round up a number with precision of two decimal places:

```
ceiling(100*$value) div 100
```

If you need trailing zeros (i.e. a *string*, not a *number*) then wrap this in `format number()`.

Comment: There may be edge cases where it's safer to use `xs:decimal` rather than `xs:double` arithmetic: `ceiling(100*xs:decimal($value)) div 100`. I'm not sure about this, but decimal feels more reliable.